# Why is my gridview refreshing when requested to do so at one point but not at another?

Tags: android, gridview

I have written a simple memory game. You click on one of 16 cards (imagebuttons), it is turned over to reveal a fruit (eg a picture of a banana) and you click another card to have it turned over and reveal it's fruit. Then, if the images match, in a second or two later these two tiles are replaced with a blank (ie removed from the board). This happens until all is removed. Also the name of the fruit is read out verbally. Everything mentioned works perfectly, the first card is turned over and the image shown, except when the second card is clicked, it never displays the fruit. The correct fruit name is spoken and I have used similar code for the second card clicked as the first card click. Can you find where I went wrong?

The key section in my code below is what appears below:
"// so two images have been selected! do they match?"

The first image updates upon clicking on it. However, Whether the first fruit clicked = the second fruit clicked, or not, the blank tile is not "turned" to reveal the image.

Code: ....continues

```
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
         { 
            int fruitselected = (int)FruitToChooseFromImages.get(position);  


             // start   
                if (position == firstfruitselpos && imagesSelectedThusFar == 1 || fruitselected == R.drawable.blank)
                    {  
                    // (if blank icon clicked) then DO NOTHING
                    }   

                else
                {   // a valid fruit has been selected, so firstly, say the fruit's name
                    int soundtoplaynow = getrightsound(position, fruitselected);
                    SoundManager.playSound(soundtoplaynow, 1);
                    // next
                    if (imagesSelectedThusFar == 0) 
                    {
                        imagesSelectedThusFar = 1;

                        firstfruitselected = fruitselected; firstfruitselpos = position;
                        FruitToDisplayImages.set(position, fruitselected);

                        MyGridviewAdapter1.notifyDataChanged();
                        gridview.invalidateViews();
                        }
                    else // so two images have been selected! do they match?
                    {
                        imagesSelectedThusFar = 0; // has reached 2, so reset to zero
                        secondfruitselected = fruitselected; secondfruitselpos = position;
                        FruitToDisplayImages.set(position, fruitselected);
                        MyGridviewAdapter1.notifyDataChanged();
                        gridview.invalidateViews();

                        try{ Thread.sleep(1500); }catch(InterruptedException e){ }

                        if (firstfruitselected == secondfruitselected) //yes they match
                            {
                            SoundManager.playSound(50, 1);// play happy sound

                            //switch fruit image to blank and display blank at position clicked **
                            FruitToDisplayImages.set(position, R.drawable.blank);
                            FruitToChooseFromImages.set(position, R.drawable.blank);

                            FruitToDisplayImages.set(firstfruitselpos, R.drawable.blank);
                            FruitToChooseFromImages.set(firstfruitselpos, R.drawable.blank);                            
                            MyGridviewAdapter1.notifyDataChanged();
                            gridview.invalidateViews();   

                            fruitleft = (fruitleft - 2);
                            }

                        else // nope, dont match
                        { // you selected the wrong fruit, sorry.
                        SoundManager.playSound(60, 1); // play UNhappy sound
                        try{ Thread.sleep(1500); }catch(InterruptedException e){ }
                        FruitToChooseFromImages.set(firstfruitselpos, firstfruitselected);
                        FruitToDisplayImages.set(firstfruitselpos, R.drawable.blanktile);
                        FruitToDisplayImages.set(secondfruitselpos, R.drawable.blanktile);
                        MyGridviewAdapter1.notifyDataChanged();
                        gridview.invalidateViews();
}   
                    }

            }    

              // end

             if (fruitleft == 0)
                { //end game - add code here
                 SoundManager.playSound(70, 1); // play big happy congrats sound

                }             }
     });
```

etc

Comment: I don't think that somebody could figure out where is the error based on your current question info. Your best bet is to debug the app and see where things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks Luksprog. I will delve into debug, of which I am woefully ignorant at this time....but not for long.

Comment: First, put some `Log` statements in your code and see if the values(+ `ArrayList` contents) you get in the `OnItemClickListener` are the values you would normally get.

Comment: post your log statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log statements told me everything was working exactly as designed behind the scenes, it just didn't upgrade the gridview like I was asking it to! I modified this code no end, using common troubleshooting practices but nothing worked. It just did the same thing.

After making the images to be displayed not reset at all but updating the view elsewhere, later in the onclick listener chain of events I discovered that the gridview would refresh/display correctly later when I called for it to update. After trying to delay the gridview update using sleep to have this same effect, thinking this was the solution and failing to solve the issue I created a handler that delayed the resetting of the tile to blank or clear thus allowing for the image to be displayed. Problem solved.